# what do I need to manage zurb-foundation gems?

Tags: zurb-foundation, bower

I have multiple projects using different versions of zurb-foundation.  I want to use the sass/compass implementation.  We have multiple people working on these projects and we need consistent authoring environments.

We aren't creating gems or anything like that, just html/css/jquery stuff.  I want to be able to set up a watch on the command line to auto-compile the css and reload the browser if possible. When we are ready for launch, we'd like to minify everything.

Right now if I try to start a new project with the latest version of Foundation, all the other projects get upgraded.  And since some upgrades break certain things - I don't want that.  Also if we have new people added, they have to install specific versions of everything.   It seems like a package manager is needed.

But every time I read about some kind of package manager, it seems like I have to install something else: ruby, homebrew, rbenv, bundler plus the zurb-foundation gem itself.  The more research I do, the more confused I get.

Can someone please make a recommendation of what is needed, where it needs to be installed and in what order?

Answer (score 0):

For Foundation 4, you can use the bundler gem. There are instructions on how to set up a Gemfile and install a specific Foundation version in the F4 official docs.

For Foundation 5, it depends on how you are using it. If you are using bower, you can specific a specific version number in the bower.json file and run bower install or bower update.

There are a variety of other ways to handle this and things might be different if for example you are using Rails, but these are the two best ways that I know of to get a specific version of Foundation installed.

Answer (score 0):

It was a Magical Mystery Tour  - and not in a good way - but I finally got it working.  Thanks to Robert Anderson: http://blog.zerosharp.com/installing-ruby-with-homebrew-and-rbenv-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/
You are my hero!  Although my experience started a bit further back...

Here's what I had to do:

1 - Update Xcode from the App store.

2 - Open and hit cmd-, and download command line tools.

**2.5 - If you have the GitHub.app installed - uninstall it.** It apparently interferes with command line operation, which really needs to be working for the rest of this.

3 - Install GIT.  I'm using Mountain Lion and couldn't find an install package for that, but the snow leopard one worked.  (http://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/files/)

4 - Go to /usr/local

5 - Install Homebrew   (http://brew.sh/) Do **NOT** use sudo.

```
 ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Now check the install:

```
$ brew doctor
```

I got a warning  about an unbrewed .pc file fuse.pc - Just a warning so moving on...

```
 $ brew update
```

If everything is installed correctly, this should run without errors.

6 - NOW you need to update your path, if you haven't already.  Create ~/.profile if it's not already there.  Add:

```
homebrew=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
export PATH=$homebrew:$PATH
```

After wrestling with this file for awhile, and researching $PATH, I ended up editing `/etc/paths` and putting  `/usr/local/bin` at the top of the stack.  I think learning how to set your path is one of the keys to getting this done.

7 - Now use Homebrew to install rbenv. rbenv lets you have more than one version of ruby running on your machine.  You need this because OSX ships with an old version of ruby that isn't supported by F5. yaay.

```
$ brew install rbenv
$ brew install ruby-build
```

Answer (score 0):

To continue...

8 - NOW you can install ruby using rbenv.  I looked up the latest stable version of ruby and it's 2.1.1.  Groovy.

```
$ rbenv install 2.1.1
$ rbenv rehash
```

Checking...

```
$ruby --version
```

I got:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```

Seriously?  Now what?  Oops - it's that nutty path thing again.  add this to `.profile`

```
# Initialize rbenv
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

Quit and restart terminal.  Check again:

```
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
```

Yaay!  High fives!  What was I doing again?  Oh yeah - Foundation.  Sigh.

9 - Go to  http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html   I already have Node.js installed - thank heaven - so now I install bower.

```
[sudo] npm install -g bower grunt-cli
```

10 - Now I install Foundation!

```
gem install foundation
```

But wait - there's more!   That's 1.0.4.  Should it be 5 something?  Well no - that's the Foundation CLI.

11 - NOW I can create my project.

```
$ cd path/to/sites
$ foundation new MY_PROJECT
```

Now I finally have a project.  Open in the browser....
I get an unstyled page:

```
Welcome to Foundation
We’re stoked you want to try Foundation!

To get going, this file (index.html) includes some basic styles you can modify, play around with, or totally destroy to get going.

Once you've exhausted the fun in this document, you should check out...
```

wah wah  Well thanks ZURB!  Yes I *have* exhausted the fun - but probably not in the way you intended.

12- Oh yeah - and bundler too so I can manage my old versions of Foundation

```
$ gem install bundler
```

So that's where I'm at. And all this so that updates are easier?

Was this ridiculously painful?  You bet.  And it's not like I'm exactly a noob here - I've done three sites with Foundation 4 - with and without compass -  and one with Bootstrap.

Thanks ZURB  - You guys may be geniuses but give the rest of us a break please!

Comment: Read the below first.  The process was too long for one post.